# codeproblem basic android programming

Tags: android

i just started android programming from coursera and i ran into some problems while doing my first assignment. i just have to create a simple app with a picture, title and text but i cant put scroll.
this is my code

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.assignment1.app1.MainActivity" >

<ScrollView
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
>

<TextView
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/title"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textSize="34sp" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="300sp"
    android:layout_below="@id/textView1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:src="@drawable/jobs"
    android:contentDescription="@string/contentdsj" />


<TextView        
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_below="@id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/Stevejobsquote"
    android:textStyle="italic"
    android:layout_marginTop="10sp"
    android:textSize="15sp" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/Stevejobsinfo"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="28sp" />

     </ScrollView>



</RelativeLayout>
```

can anyone help me ?

Comment: As you are learning, you should try to understand why XML is **not** code.  It's data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `ScrollView` can only have one child in order to operate properly, make a Layout that gathers all the children of it and make the `ScrollView` it's parent:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.assignment1.app1.MainActivity" >

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:text="@string/title"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="34sp" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="300sp"
                android:layout_below="@id/textView1"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:contentDescription="@string/contentdsj"
                android:src="@drawable/jobs" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/imageView1"
                android:layout_marginTop="10sp"
                android:text="@string/Stevejobsquote"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:textStyle="italic" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/Stevejobsinfo"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="28sp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as i remember, ScrollView can have only one direct child so create a layout inside your ScrollView and put everything, you need to scroll, inside that layout and it should work!

Answer (score 0):

Scrollview must hold only one child:

> **A ScrollView is a FrameLayout, meaning you should place one child in it containing the entire contents to scroll**; this child may itself
>   be a layout manager with a complex hierarchy of objects. A child that
>   is often used is a LinearLayout in a vertical orientation, presenting
>   a vertical array of top-level items that the user can scroll through.

So additionally you need to wrap all your widgets into i.e. `LinearLayout`

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html